# Django - passing data and redirecting between views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a project related to quizzes online and I'm stuck at the moment where I want to pass data from one view to another. My goal is to get a quiz name from the user in the form in one view and pass it to another view, after submitting a form.

I've made 2 views:

- add() - which has the first form with the name for the quiz and redirects to add_questions with the name of the quiz
- add_questions() - which captures the name of the submitted quiz and displays another form for the questions

views.py

```py
    @login_required
    def add(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            QuizForm = QuizNameForm(request.POST)
            if QuizForm.is_valid():
                # create a quiz
                new_quiz = QuizForm.save(commit=False)
                new_quiz.owner = request.user
                new_quiz.save()

                request.session['quiz_id'] = new_quiz.id
                print("Quiz saved, now I'm redirecting to add_questions")
                return redirect(add_questions)
                #return HttpResponseRedirect('add_questions') ---  didn't work
                #return render(request, 'quiz/add_questions.html', {}) --- didn't work
        else: 
            QuizForm = QuizNameForm()
        return render(request, 'quiz/add.html', {'quizForm': QuizForm})

    @login_required
    def add_questions(request):
        print("Add questions here! I've captured a quiz named: {}".format(quiz.name))
        quiz = DB_questions.objects.get(id=request.session['quiz_id'])
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("ok, post method - cool")
        #create a question/answer forms
        else:
            print("Got into else in add_questions view")
            Question_form = QuestionForm()

        return render(request, 'quiz/add_questions.html', {'quiz_name': quiz.name, 'question_form': Question_form })
```

My template for adding quiz name - templates/add.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <!-- Get name of the quiz-->
            <form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ quizForm.name }}
                <input class="btn btn-success w-100" type="submit" value="Proceed">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Template to display the name and question form - templates/add_question.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
    <h2 class="select_title"> Quiz: {{ quiz_name }}</h2>
    <div class="col-md-5"></div>
</div>

<form action="{% url 'add_questions' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ question_form.content }}
</form>
```

And finally the urls.py

```py
    urlpatterns = [
        # ...
        url(r'^add', views.add, name='add'),
        url(r'^add_questions', views.add_questions, name='add_questions'),
    ]
```

The main problem is that after submitting the quiz name the system adds a quiz into database but doesn't redirect me to "add_questions". It still stays in "add" view.

Also I'm not sure if that's the proper way of how I should implement it. I've found many different ways of how I could do it but none of those worked out for me. (Solutions like HttpResponseRedirect(), redirect(), render() etc.)

To sum up:

1) What's the best way, in this case, to transfer data between views after submiting it in the form?

2) How should I redirect to another view so that it would display proper template?

Comment: you need to give the view name to redirect function. `return redirect('add_questions')`.  Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this should work fine for you:
views.py:

```py
    @login_required
    def add(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            QuizForm = QuizNameForm(request.POST)
            if QuizForm.is_valid():
                # create a quiz
                new_quiz = QuizForm.save(commit=False)
                new_quiz.owner = request.user
                new_quiz.save()

                print("Quiz saved, now I'm redirecting to add_questions")
                return render(request, 'quiz/add_questions.html', {'quiz_id': new_quiz.id})
        else: 
            QuizForm = QuizNameForm()
        return render(request, 'quiz/add.html', {'quizForm': QuizForm})

    @login_required
    def add_questions(request):
        quiz = DB_questions.objects.get(id=request['quiz_id'])
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("ok, post method - cool")
        #create a question/answer forms
        else:
            print("Got into else in add_questions view")
            Question_form = QuestionForm()

        return render(request, 'quiz/add_questions.html', {'quiz_name': quiz.name, 'question_form': Question_form })
```

This way you can both render your template and also send the *quiz_id* through the request object (not session).